# Generating a multipoint topojson file

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, topojson

I am trying to create a map layer using D3 and leaflet for displaying a large number of unique GPS data points. I created it using geoJSON and Leaflet but the performance was poor. I finally got Topojson installed and working, but I cannot get it to produce a Multipoint geometry, only Point geometry which does not shrink the file much. I have passed in a CSV with all the points and used to geoJson file but only get 70,000 point geometries instead of one Multipoint. What am I missing? Do I need to write the Topojson myself? Want to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

TopoJSON won't help you in this case. To quote [the website](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson):

> Rather than representing geometries discretely, geometries in TopoJSON files are stitched together from shared line segments called arcs.

As you have no line segments, there's no point in using TopoJSON -- it won't reduce the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

+1 What Lars said. Your best bet is probably to load the point data as a CSV using `d3.csv()`instead of a GeoJSON or TopoJSON, as it is much more compact. You can then loop over the data, adding each point to a layer group.

That said, 70,000 is a lot and your map is still probably going to be very slow. You might want to think about using something like PostGIS (or CartoDB for that matter) and request only those points that are visible in a given map state.